# retrive empty or null value of date from datagridview ? VB Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, null

```
        Dim datagrid1 As Date = Nothing
        Dim remaning1 As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim answer1 As Integer = Nothing


        datagrid1 = DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value
```

if datagridview value is empty then there is an error. How to rectify this issue.

Comment: use an `If` statement to check?

Comment: @plutonix yes.. is there any easy way ? because I have so many different date variables

Comment: `Dim datagrid1 As Date = Nothing` - sets `datagrid1` to `DateTime.MinValue`. `Dim answer1 As Integer = Nothing` sets `answer1` to `0`

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` will help

Answer (score 1):

Do a check whether the value is null and set the value accordingly:

```
            If Not IsDBNull(DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value) Then
                datagrid1.Value = DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear... but I think you want to check that the value in the DataGridView is a valid date... If so, use the below

```
If TypeOf(DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value) Is Date Then
   'Logic here...
End If
```